# Save specific info to txt from python shell

Tags: python

Is it possible to save the information that is output to python shell into a txt file.

I'm running Python version 2.7.2

This is what's displayed in the shell.

```
Enter numbers 1... 22,34,35,40,55
Enter numbers 2... 12,14,34,47,49
Enter numbers 3... 1,4,10,19,30
Section 1
The number seqeuce is # 0 0 1 2 1 1 # <-- 
Section 2                         
The number seqeuce is # 0 2 0 1 2 0 # <-- This is what I would like to save to txt.
Section 3                         
The number seqeuce is # 2 2 0 1 0 0 # <--
```

I've looked around and understand how to read, write and append files but not 
directly from the shell.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its exactly the same in the shell, but you will basically be running the code one line at a time, instead of just running a file with it all together. Otherwise, you could just copy/paste the results...
Not quite sure if that's what you were looking for, please let me know if it's not.

Comment: Th code that is writen is asking the question and the shell gives the answer.  I want to save the answer directly from the shell if possible.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do that would be to copy/paste the answer, honestly. Otherwise, you can try digging around [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) or [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 0):

```
  >> numbers = input("Enter numbers")
  >> with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as f:
       f.write('The number sequence is {0}'.format(numbers.replace(',', ' '))
```

If input was `22,34,35,40,55`, output to file would be `The number sequence is 22 34 35 40 55`

You just have to type each command into the shell. When you run a `.py` script, the interpreter is just evaluating your code line by line, just as the shell is doing when you type commands into it.